# Will “ground hornets” come back to the same place after winter?

Tags: entomology

We recently moved into a new house and when we mowed the yard we were being stung by these huge hornets. We couldn’t find anyone to remove them and I am terrified they are going to come back this year. They are in the ground and are about 1-2 inches long and chunky. They also come out at night when we are trying to sit on the patio. I need some advice. If they will be there this year, what can I do to rid of them.

Comment: Welcome to the Biology Stack Exchange. Please take a [tour] and visit the [help] page for more information on this site and how it works. There are quite a few different wasp/hornet species world-wide and this question will probably need an ID to be able to answer properly. If you can, can you please edit in a picture of the insects in question and a location in the world - something like your nearest major city and/or state and country usually works well.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are likely to return to the same zone and garden if it is a good habitat for them.

Knowledge of them will protect you, and give you confidence that you can reclaim your garden.

1/ research [dissuasion](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+dissuade+%22ground+hornets%22) of ground hornets.

2/ put together some protective clothing, in case you have to spray a biocontrol agent or another deterrent. I don't know what your budget is, but you could get by with a hat protected by netting, from some instructions online, and some gloves, they won't swarm you in great hives.

3/ Invest in a lot of diligent research, to know what month they start burrowing, what day temperature they prefer to wake up to, how to protect yourself physically if you have to approach an active nesting hornet, if it's ok to keep a good long-handle net near the porch and intercept them when they venture too close in the evening. Read stories of others who have had the same adventure.

I am an experienced zoologist I have been stung by wasps many times, and fortunately not a hornet.

I climbed a tree with 20 in nest just above me and climbed down again, and many other encounters.

The biggest danger is that a wasp or bee falls in a cola when someone is briefly distracted.

Folk should know to be conscious of not mouth-breathing when running near them, and what to do if your friend is stung inside the throat on a hike far from help and breathing becomes difficult.

With this knowledge, I am became confident to let wasps and bees forage and walk on my hands and face which can be annoying after a minute or if they insist on foraging over an eyelid or a nostril, however it is better than startling them, I know how to tell the difference between more and less aggressive lookalikes based on their flying patterns, leg length in flight and other markers, It's a good thing to teach children. I became confident to stay very calm near a hornet nest and try to avoid it, to immediately suck a wasp sting and very fast put cola, or vinegar is better, on a sting, to greatly diminish its effect, and run fast if a nest is disturbed so they go into an aggressive mode.

Good luck.